# Angularjs Route does not seem to be working

Tags: angularjs

I have 4 file index.html,test.html, module.js, and name.json

For some reason it doesnt seem to be working for my on my localhost. Either my code is wrong or my routes are wrong I just want to display my test.html page.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html data-ng-app = "mysite">

<head>

    <title>Practice with Angular</title>

</head>

<body>

    <div>

        <div data-ng-view = ""></div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src = "http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src = "module.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**test.html**

```
<div>

    <input data-ng-model = "search" type = "text">

    <table>

        <tr>

            <th><a href="" data-ng-click = "sortfield = 'name'">Names</a></th>

        </tr>

        <tr data-ng-repeat = "x in names | filter : search | orderBy : sortfield">

            <td>

                {{x.name}}

            </td>

        </tr>

    </table>

    <p>Welcome {{search}}</p>

</div>
```

**module.js**

```
var app = angular.module("mysite", []);

app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {

            controller : "name-controller",
            templateUrl : "test.html"


        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : "/"});

});

app.controller("name-controller", function($scope, $http){

    $http.get("name.json").success(function(data){

        $scope.names = data;

    });

});
```

**name.json**

```
[
{"name" : "nelson"},
{"name" : "shirley"},
{"name" : "jenny"},
{"name" : "darrick"},
{"name" : "yen"},
{"name" : "mom"},
{"name" : "dad"},
{"name" : "coreen"}
]
```

Comment: "*it doesn't seem to be working*" is not very descriptive. Care to elaborate? Are you getting any errors?  Is the behavior you observe different from what you intended?

Comment: Do you use some kind of web server?

Comment: when I load my html file its blank i was expecting the test.html to be loaded into the ng view.

Comment: yes I am using wamp server to load my files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/t6qgL9P7zDBfEUp6385N?p=preview

a) please add reference to angular-route.js 
b) inject ngRoute into your angular module `var app = angular.module('mysite', ['ngRoute']);`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app = "mysite">

  <head>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>


<body >

  <div ng-view="">

  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('mysite', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){

    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {

            controller : "name-controller",
            templateUrl : "test.html"


        })
        .otherwise({ redirectTo : "/"});

});
app.controller("name-controller", function($scope, $http){

    $http.get("name.json").success(function(data){

        $scope.names = data;

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the ng-view directive should be written as: `<div data-ng-view></div>`. You will also need to name your controller from within test.html.